# Syncfusion MVC Report Viewer Parameters from Query

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, reporting-services, syncfusion

Im trying to render SSRS Parameters on Syncfusion Report Viewer with Razor Engine

How can i do this?

Can i do this without define hardcoded parameters on my Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can able to pass the parameter values to report from Razor View as shown in below code example.

```
        @(Html.EJ().ReportViewer("reportsample")
.ProcessingMode(Syncfusion.JavaScript.ReportViewerEnums.ProcessingMode.Remote).ReportServiceUrl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/api/SSRSReport")).ReportServerUrl("http://mvc.syncfusion.com/reportserver").ReportPath("/Report Project1/InvoiceTemplate")
                              .Parameters(param =>
                              {
                               param.Name("InvoiceID").Labels(new List<string>() { "InvoiceID" }).Values(new List<string>() { "10250" }).Add();
                              })
        )
```

Also, you can able to  populate the parameter values from query as given in below MSDN articles,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157187.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Please refer the below UG documentation for more details on this,
http://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/reportviewer/report-parameters